# X-Editable Installation

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, x-editable

My question is:
I am dynamically generating divs from MySQL table Rows and I want to edit them inline using X-Edit, so I installed the files (first I tried the bootstrap version but now the jQueryUI version) and the framework files (jQueryUI) created a link around the headline for my divs which only says: "Enter Headline" ... so I tried to declare the parameters directly in the  tag via data-* but this did'nt worked. so I tried to declare them via JavaScript ... this didn't work neither...

```
$('#headline').editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
});
```

This should do the work?
I'm not speaking about the backend atm..

It would be great if someone could help me.

Best Regards
Dave

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What the console screams about

Comment: nothing. it is just a link to #

Comment: I've brought it to work via plain jQuery which is ok.


To the backend part:
what value does 'pk' gets?
and is value automatically in the $_POST Array?

Comment: Check the console, it says what is requested, which request method is used, the key - value pair, response, etc...